# Kubectl gives "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp i/o timeout

Tags: tcp, kubectl, minikube

I have installed minikube and kubectl on Ubuntu 16.04LTS
However when i try any command with kubectl it give the below error:
`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp x.x.x.x:x i/o timeout`

kubectl version only gives client version. The server version is not dispalyed
Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: It means that kube-apiserver is not contactable. Please show your debug steps and your config (eg. kubeconfig, config of kube-apiserver). No one help you with so little information.

Comment: @EugeneChow thank you for your reply. I have resolved this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to ensure the interface was up and running.
So a `sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up` resolved the issue.

Comment: @LingboTang my question was specific to Ubuntu 16.04. So I could resolve the problem with this. I am sorry I will not be able to help you in this case

Comment: Can you share what was your fix?